Need help with this Box and Bulbs probability problem
There are 2 boxes containing bulbs, In the fist box, there are a total of 20 bulbs and 4 of them aren't working. In the second box, there are 12 bulbs and 3 of them aren't working. We pick 5 bulbs from the first box and 7 bulbs from the second box and put them in a new box. What is the probability that atleast one of the chosen bulbs from the new (third) box is not working?
A) 5/24 | B) 11/48 | C) 13/48 | D) 7/24
At first I thought if atleast one of them is supposed not to work then I'm gonna use the formula 1-P(A') = P(A) Where P(A') is the probability that all of them work. but that didn't work as we don't have a specific number of how many are we picking. I guess that's what makes it hard.

Write your workings by editing your question, please. This will help your question be well-received.

What is the chance that one of the bulbs you picked from the first box isn't working?

Well, the probability for selecting $5$ from the $16$ working bulbs among the $20$ bulbs in the first box is: $$\dfrac{\dbinom{16}{5}}{\dbinom{20}{5}} = \dfrac{16\cdot15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12}{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot15\cdot14}$$ .

Answer is B
In the first box, 4 bulbs out of 20 do not work so there is a 4/20 probability that the bulb will not work. Similarly in the second box, 3 bulbs out of 12 do not work so there is a 3/12 probability that the bulb will not work.
Now we are choosing 5 bulbs from box 1 and we know that the probability that the bulb we choose does not work is 1/5 (4/20 reduced). So when we choose 5 bulbs there is a 5(1/5) chance that the bulb doesnt work. In the same way we choose 7 bulbs from box 2 so the final probability is 7(1/4) (3/12 is reduced).
Now to get probability of the bulb working in the 3rd box, we add the total chances of getting a bulb that doesn't work and divide it by total number of possibilites ie total number of bulbs in 3rd box. So we get (1+ 7/4)÷12 which equals 11/48.
Hope it helps.

How can you have a probability of $7/4$? Probabilities must be between $0$ and $1$.

Can you please explain the method you used for this problem? It's the first time I've seen it.
